# Store code snippet containing new lines for display in Ace editor

Tags: javascript, newline, ace-editor

I want to pre-populate an Ace instance with a code snippet.
The code snippet is hard-coded in a string.

Since Ace, naturally, displays the literal content of the string,
new line (/n) gets displayed as '/n', and does not result in a
new line.

How do I encode the new line as part of my string so that it
actually produces a new line in Ace?

EDIT: As stated below: '/n' is not '\n' - seems I need to work
on my reading skills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New line is `\n` not `/n`

Otherwise ace snippet syntax is the same as textmate/snipmate.